# Error when inserting image in MySQL with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am new to PHP, I make a form to insert in a database and I can not insert an error when I want to insert the image, in the database the type of the image is "longblob", I enclose the form and the. PHPto insert in the database.

Form:

```
<form align="center" action="guardar.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="text" REQUIRED name="titulo" placeholder="Titulo.." value=""/><br><br>
    <input type="text" REQUIRED name="contenido" placeholder="Contenido.." value=""/><br><br>
    <input type="text" REQUIRED name="fecha" placeholder="Fecha.." value=""/><br><br>
    <input type="file" REQUIRED name="imagen" /><br><br>
    <input type="submit" name="Aceptar" />
</form>
```

PHP

```
<?php

include("conexion.php");

$titulo=$_POST['titulo'];
$contenido=$_POST['contenido'];
$fecha=$_POST['fecha'];
$imagen=addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['imagen']['tmp_name']));

$query="INSERT INTO articulos(titulo,contenido,fecha,imagen) VALUES('$titulo','$contenido','$fecha','$imagen')";

mysqli_query($conexion, $query);
$resultado=$conexion->query($query);

if($resultado){
    echo "INSERT";
}else{
    echo "No INSERT";
}

?>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [Your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](//stackoverflow.com/q/60174). Simply put, don't use `addslashes`, `mysql*_escape_string`. You should be binding the actual variables to your query.

Comment: It's better to save image on the server  and save in the db only a refer to the img

Comment: Why are you using `file_get_contents()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use `file_get_contents()`, this is the wrong function for this - it does something else entirely (you can read the manual if you are curious what this function does). Instead of using a query that injects values directly, you should also use a prepared statement, as shown below.

This will prevent SQL-injection attacks, and make sure that no data will break the query.

```
<?php

include "conexion.php";

$titulo = $_POST['titulo'];
$contenido = $_POST['contenido'];
$fecha = $_POST['fecha'];
$imagen = $_FILES['imagen']['tmp_name'];

$query = "INSERT INTO articulos (titulo, contenido, fecha, imagen) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";

if ($stmt = $conexion->prepare($query)) {
    $stmt->bind_param("ssss", $titulo, $contenido, $fecha, $imagen);
    if ($stmt->execute()) {
        echo "Inserted");
    } else {
        // Do some logging
        error_log($stmt->error);
        echo "Not inserted";
    }
} else {
    // Do some logging
    error_log($conexion->error);
    echo "Not inserted";
}
```